# Hanging Indent within a table (htm)

Tags: html, indentation

I am trying to create a hanging indent within a table cell with HTML.

I have found the code for just adding a regular hanging indent:

```
<div style="text-indent: -36px; padding-left: 36px;">  
</div>
```

This works great but only with text outside of the table. When I try and place it in a table, I don't see any changes?

This is an example of one of the tables I have:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">

    <tbody>

        <tr>

            <td class="ck_border" style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"><em>Works Cited:</em></td>

            <td class="ck_border" style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"> lots of text here 
</td>
```

I would like the "lots of text here" bit to be formatted as a hanging indent.

Is this possible? I'm sorry if I've included too much information, again, I'm new to this and figured too much was better than not enough.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to apply the hanging indent to the second td's text content?

Comment: Yes. Only in the one table cell

Answer (score 0):

Same principle as your example, but a selector to effect `:not(:first-child)` which you could also do an `td:nth-child(#)` selector instead to target specific columns if you like. Cheers.

```css
td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: lightgray 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
}

td:not(:first-child) {
  border: green 1px dashed;
  text-indent: -1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>More stuff with more words that says something for someone with a hanging indent...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>More stuff with more words that says something for someone with a hanging indent...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm using Sprinshare (writing a libguide) and I'm only able to edit in HTML, not CSS. Will I be able to input this code?

Comment: Opps! Had meant to thank you too!

Comment: @tetanya13 I'm not familiar with springshare directly, but if you can edit the html than I assume you could just add the css to the html of the table cell you're editing? So that table cell would look instead like `<td style="text-indent: -1rem;padding-left: 2rem;">` for just that `td` column. Then tweak the size to your liking.

Comment: You are the best! I spent forever trying to figure this out. Thank you!!

Comment: @tetanya13 no problem, happy holidays!